# br tag not closing in Haml on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am having a problem getting Haml to close br tags.  I have tried the following with no luck:

```
%br  
%br/
```

I expect this to result in `<br />`, but it always outputs as `<br>`, even with the slash character on the end.  I have also tried adding the following options to application.rb (and I tried environment.rb)

```
Haml::Template.options[:autoclose] = ['meta', 'img', 'link', 'br', 'hr', 'input', 'area', 'param', 'col', 'base']
```

Am I missing something?  I though Haml was supposed to autoclose these tags by default??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found out the problem.  Haml outputs HTML5 by default when using Rails 3.  I didn't realize that `<br>` was valid syntax in HTML5.  I was trying to get this to pass the W3C semantic extractor, so I need `<br />` instead.  In order to get this to work, you will need to update the Haml options for autoclose and set it to xhtml.  Drop this code into your application.rb inside the class.

```
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :xhtml
```

More info here:

http://github.com/nex3/haml/issuesearch?state=closed&q=close#issue/155

Comment: You don't actually need to adjust the `:autoclose` list. Haml knows that `<br>` should be autoclosed by default.

Comment: @nex3 - answer updated to reflect that.  thanks for the tip, and thanks for your hard work on haml and sass.  Awesome products!

Answer (score 2):

But, if I want xhtml5 (i.e. html5 with autoclose) there's no way to do it!  I, like many other users, have tried overriding the :autoclose list and it just doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using `%br &nbsp;` -- Ugly, repetitive, but does the job.

Answer (score 1):

According to the haml docs:

```
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :xhtml
```

should be placed in config/environment.rb.

Placing it in environment.rb works for me.