# Haml: source end tag(</source>) is not yielded

Tags: haml

I am using Haml(ver3.1.2) in Rails(ver3.1).

```
Haml:
%audio{ :controls => 'controls' }
  %source{ :src => 'http://apptestdata.s3.amazonaws.com/audio/brand/brand2.m4a' }
  %source{ :src => 'http://apptestdata.s3.amazonaws.com/audio/brand/brand2.wav' }

Html(yielded by above Haml):
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="http://apptestdata.s3.amazonaws.com/audio/brand/brand2.m4a">
    <source src="http://apptestdata.s3.amazonaws.com/audio/brand/brand2.wav">
</audio>
```

There are no errors in Safari, but are errors in IE9, because there is nothing source end tag(`</source>`).

Can I insert source end tag(`</source>`)?

Comment: autoclose xhtml as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079232/br-tag-not-closing-in-haml-on-rails-3.  Too bad about IE9, though.... Why does it complain?

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options

You can add the <source> tag to `:autoclose`, which may help you to close the tag